# jhipster test integrationTest: fails saying '/home/dave/jhipster-learn/online-store/bin/default/src/main/webapp/app/app-page-title-strategy.ts' file

Tags: testing, integration

I know the file exists as I can see it in my file browser.
This is an unmodified jhispter app generated from a JDL file.
I am a complete novice for jhipster, java, spring and all the other technolgies used.
I'm trying to follow the example in the "Full Stack Development with JHipster" book (its a bit behind the coal-face).
JDL file is:

```
application {
  config {
    applicationType monolith
    authenticationType jwt
    baseName store
    buildTool gradle
    cacheProvider caffeine
    clientFramework angular
    clientTheme none
    creationTimestamp 1709222117663
    databaseType sql
    devDatabaseType h2Disk
    enableHibernateCache true
    enableSwaggerCodegen false
    enableTranslation false
    feignClient false
    jhipsterVersion "8.1.0"
    jwtSecretKey "YjVkNzMxYjQyOGYzYjJlZjdmZmU4NmM0MTkyZDYzYTA4YTBmZDBiMzZlNzdjYjJlZWE2MTRmNTA5N2Q4NWY0MjVhZjVkYjlkMGIxMzM0MjQ2ZDkyNWYxYjk2MTc4Y2YxZjQyOWJiNzFiMzE4ZDA4MTU5ZmI0OWQ2ZmUwZWQ2MTY="
    messageBroker false
    microfrontends []
    nativeLanguage en
    packageName matchless
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    reactive false
    searchEngine false
    serviceDiscoveryType false
    testFrameworks [cypress, gatling]
    websocket spring-websocket
    withAdminUi true
  }

  entities Customer, Invoice, OrderItem, Product, ProductCategory, ProductOrder, Shipment
}

@ChangelogDate("20240229155817")
entity Customer {
  firstName String required
  lastName String required
  gender Gender required
  email String required pattern(/^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+$/)
  phone String required
  addressLine1 String required
  addressLine2 String
  city String required
  country String required
}
@ChangelogDate("20240229160117")
entity Invoice {
  code String required
  date Instant required
  details String
  status InvoiceStatus required
  paymentMethod PaymentMethod required
  paymentDate Instant required
  paymentAmount BigDecimal required
}
@ChangelogDate("20240229160017")
entity OrderItem {
  quantity Integer required min(0)
  totalPrice BigDecimal required min(0)
  status OrderItemStatus required
}
/**
 * Product sold by the Online store
 */
@ChangelogDate("20240229155617")
entity Product {
  name String required
  description String
  price BigDecimal required min(0)
  fit Fit required
  image ImageBlob
}
@ChangelogDate("20240229155717")
entity ProductCategory {
  name String required
  description String
}
@ChangelogDate("20240229155917")
entity ProductOrder {
  placedDate Instant required
  status OrderStatus required
  code String required
}
@ChangelogDate("20240229160217")
entity Shipment {
  trackingCode String
  date Instant required
  details String
}
enum Gender {
  MALE,
  FEMALE,
  OTHER
}
enum InvoiceStatus {
  PAID,
  ISSUED,
  CANCELLED
}
enum PaymentMethod {
  CREDIT_CARD,
  CASH_ON_DELIVERY,
  PAYPAL
}
enum OrderItemStatus {
  AVAILABLE,
  OUT_OF_STOCK,
  BACK_ORDER
}
enum Fit {
  S,
  M,
  L,
  XL,
  XXL
}
enum OrderStatus {
  COMPLETED,
  PENDING,
  CANCELLED
}

relationship OneToOne {
  Customer{user(login) required} to User with builtInEntity
}
relationship OneToMany {
  Customer{order} to ProductOrder{customer(email) required}
  Invoice{shipment} to Shipment{invoice(code) required}
  ProductCategory{product} to Product{productCategory(name)}
  ProductOrder{orderItem} to OrderItem{order(code) required}
  ProductOrder{invoice} to Invoice{order(code) required}
}
relationship ManyToOne {
  OrderItem{product(name) required} to Product
}

paginate Customer, Invoice, OrderItem, Product, ProductOrder, Shipment with pagination
service * with serviceClass
search * with no
```

I was expecting a non-modified app to pass the integration tests.
The error message is misleading and I have no idea where to go to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The title got truncated. The issue is it reports a file is missing when it is not.